# Python do a lookup between 2 dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, lookup

I am trying to *summarise two dictionaries* as follows:

```
mydict = {41100: 'Health Grant',
 50050: 'Salaries',
 50150: 'Salaries',
 50300: 'Salaries'};
mytb = {'': '',
 41100: -3,450,200.40,
 50050: 1,918,593.96,
 50150: 97.50,
 50300: 8,570.80}
```

My output should be:

> { 'Health Grant': -3450200.40, 'Salaries': 1927262.26 }

Can you help with *coding the for loop code* pls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine Python dictionaries that have the same Key name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626202/combine-python-dictionaries-that-have-the-same-key-name)

Comment: You should try creating the loop first before asking for help. Remember that this site helps others that might have the same question. Something like this could be done after searching "python lloops"

Comment: @Sandman The questions are similar, but not duplicate. The dicts have the same keys, but OP wants to use the values form the first dict as keys in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate the keys and values of the first dict and add the values from the second dict corresponding to the same key.

```
mydict = {41100: 'Health Grant', 50050: 'Salaries', 50150: 'Salaries', 50300: 'Salaries'};
mytb = {'': '', 41100: -3450200.40, 50050: 1918593.96, 50150: 97.50, 50300: 8570.80}

result = {}
for key, value in mydict.items():
    result[value] = result.get(value, 0) + mytb[key]
```

Or using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in mydict.items():
    result[value] += mytb[key]
```

In both cases, `result` will be `{'Health Grant': -3450200.4, 'Salaries': 1927262.26}`